# Autocomplete for paper-input

Tags: polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

Using the Dart/Polymer framwork the `autocomplete` attribute works with `input` or `iron-input`, but when I try the same with `paper-input` it doesn't work. All tests are done on dart2js builds, with Chrome to have the autofill with data.

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <template>
          <input is="iron-input" id="email" autocomplete="email"/>
          <paper-input id="name" autocomplete="name"/>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

In my environment both `input` and `iron-input` are dependent on having id set. If id is removed the autocomplete doesn't work. Actually it doesn't uses the value in attribute `autocomplete` apart from being different from off.

```
<input is="iron-input" id="email" autocomplete="on"/>
```

If the id is used for autocomplete, then `paper-input` shouldn't work because the underlying input element doesn't have the same id. Looking in the spec https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
it should be sufficient with just `autocomplete="name"`

Any ideas on how this is working?

Comment: For paper-input there seems to be a problem with the autocomplete. Wrote an issue on this. https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/issues/126